# Is Firefox Quantum having problems with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari

I've been trying to load more content after scrolling to the bottom of the page using the following piece of code (this solution was used as an answer to several questions here on stackoverflow):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            // AJAX
        }
    });
});
```

When I tested this in Firefox Quantum, it behaved in a very weird way, sometimes working, sometimes not, when I tried it in Safari, it worked flawlessly. Does Firefox have problems with methods used or the if statement? Thanks.

Comment: Did you do any debugging to see what was happening? Logging the two values being compared with `console.log`, for example?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, one of the first things I've tried, everything seemed to be in order. Tried it again, the math checks out.

Comment: It can be, that Firefox goes in different steps. So they both never meet equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Firefox was secretly interpreting `$(window).scrollTop()` as a floating point value, adding small values to the integer, for example, 834 wasn't 834 but 834.05, therefore, the condition was never met. Using `Math.ceil()` solved the problem, since the number was always smaller than it should've been. Maybe using <=, >= as @obey had suggested could solve the problem as well, however, I've found that the condition would trigger multiple times, which was undesirable for my project. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your equality is a bit strict, and event is not triggered. Try using >= or <= instead of ==

Something like this:

```
$(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height()
```